# UUID.randomUUID().getLeastSignificantBits() always returns negative values?

Tags: java, uuid

I need to generate a unique long value, so I decided to use UUID:

```
UUID.randomUUID().getLeastSignificantBits();
```

One strange thing I noticed was that `UUID.randomUUID().getLeastSignificantBits()` always returned negative values. I am confused. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29):

> Version 4 UUIDs use a scheme relying only on random numbers. This algorithm sets the version number (4 bits) as well as two reserved bits. All other bits (the remaining 122 bits) are set using a random or pseudorandom data source.
>
> Version 4 UUIDs have the form xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx where x is any hexadecimal digit and y is one of 8, 9, A, or B

So the first bit of the least significant half will always be a 1, making it a negative number.

Comment: Thanks. It make make sense to me. BTW, any suggestion on how to generate a unique long value?

Comment: @Kai That's a separate question (and one that has been asked before on this site).

Comment: How about SecureRandom#nextLong ?

Answer (score 1):

This may also be useful to demonstrate what to expect from `getLeastSignificantBits()`:

```
/**
 * @see UUID#getLeastSignificantBits()
 */
public void test_getLeastSignificantBits() {
    UUID uuid = new UUID(0, 0);
    assertEquals(0, uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
    uuid = new UUID(0, Long.MIN_VALUE);
    assertEquals(Long.MIN_VALUE, uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
    uuid = new UUID(0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    assertEquals(Long.MAX_VALUE, uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
}
```

[source](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/harmony/enhanced/archive/classlib/java6/modules/luni/src/test/java/org/apache/harmony/luni/tests/java/util/UUIDTest.java)